# Laravel DB statement - Create database not working

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel

I want to create a new database with laravel at runtime.

I have try with this

```
$v_db_name = "db_new";
$strSql = "CREATE DATABASE ".$v_db_name;
DB::statement($strSql);
```

It doesn't show any error I have checked the laravel log nothing is there.

But I try the same code for creating the new table then It is working but creates a new database is not working.

Comment: maybe you don't have permission for it.

Comment: @ADyson I am working on my local, how can I set the permission if it is not there?

Comment: log into MySQL as root (or other account which has sufficient permissions that it can assign permissions to others) and set the permissions from there. I don't know if you use MySQL Workbench or some other tool to administer your MySQL, but use whatever tool suits you

Comment: But it's only a guess. I am surprised there is no error or exception at all. Are you sure you're not suppressing errors in PHP or something?

Comment: A way to test the permissions would be to log into MySQL (again using Workbench or whatever) using the account which Laravel uses to connect, and running the CREATE DATABASE command there...see what happens when you run it directly using that account.

Comment: @ADyson yes there is not error at all.

Comment: @ADyson I can create a database with the same user from adminer

Comment: How have you checked that the database hasn't been created? If you have checked in a DB client, remember to refresh your top view to view newly created databases

Comment: @Daniel I didn't found newly create database in adminer, I have checked by login again

Comment: @Yes Daniel you are right, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing your statement with this instead:

```
DB::getConnection()->statement("CREATE DATABASE ".$v_db_name, array('schema' => $v_db_name));
```

Comment: If you read the comment then you found that I already got the answer Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try with 
$strSql = "CREATE DATABASE ".$v_db_name;
DB::raw($strSql);

Comment: If you read the comment then you found that I already got the answer Thanks